# How does SLSQP(Sequential least squares programming) algorithm work?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, constraints

I am implementing scipy.optimize.minimize package to minimize a function. It has been learnt that for constrained minimization, the scipy library uses SLSQP(Sequential least squares programming) by default. I went through the paper of the SLSQP algorithm but could not completely understand the basic of it as it is too mathematical. Can someone help me to understand the algorithm in simple words or text? I just want to understand how does the algorithm minimizes a constrained problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: SLSQP is an SQP method: it replaces the original problem with a sequence of Quadratic Problems (QP) whose objective are second-order approximations of the Lagrangian and whose constraints are the linearized original constraints. It then uses globalization techniques to guarantee convergence whatever the initial point. Do you have more concrete questions I can address?

Comment: Maybe Charlie's answer is better than this, but more is more:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808494/how-does-the-slsqp-optimization-algorithm-work